# Optional filter file in Maven

Tags: maven-2, build, build-process, jenkins

I have the following filters configured in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
...
    <filters>
        <filter>build.properties</filter>
        <filter>user.properties</filter>
    </filters>
...
</build>
```

`build.properties` contains filters that are used for when the webapp is built for production.  `user.properties` is where users override filters configured in `build.properties` for local deployment and testing (e.g. `servername=localhost` instead of `servername=productionserver.com`).

`user.properties` is not stored in source control, as it is local to each developer.  When we build the webapp with Jenkins, it fails with "Error loading property file".

Is there any way to designate filters as optional, or tell Maven to ignore missing filters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at setting up different maven build profiles for server builds and developer workstation builds

- http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Seems to be the best solution

Comment: It would be useful to indicate some configuration here. I've spent 5 min so far trying to figure out options of achieving this. I also don't know (yet) whether profiles will support loading ${user.name}.properties dynamically, or if I'm meant to specify a different configuration format :(.